# Re-arranging a simple formula

Tags: linear-algebra

If

$$a = \frac{b  d  e}{b  f}$$

How do I re-write the formula in the case where I know $a$ but want to find the value of $b$.

Regards
Jacob

Comment: Since you tagged abstract (now linear) algebra : What are you operations and algebraic structure? Or do you simply have reals and have a pre-calculus question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of luck.

Note that $$\require{cancel} a = \frac{\cancel{b} \cdot d \cdot e}{\cancel{b} \cdot f} = \frac{d\cdot e}{f}$$

That is, $b$ can be any value except $0$. Whatever its value, it has no impact on $a$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's why I'm struggling!

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)